# Set SSL on subdomain with htaccess - main domain is working on ssl

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to use ssl from main domain to be used on subdomain? Here is how domains are stored on vps server:

/domains/**maindomain.com**/public_html/somepagefiles

/domains/**subdomain.maindomain.com**/public_html/somepagefilesforsubdomain

MainDomain has ssl turned on and it's working. I've tried something like this with no success:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain.maindomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ssubdomain.maindomain.com/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic SSL Certificates are issued for one subdomain only. For example: `www.example.com`, where `www` is the subdomain.

There are two ways to get SSL on your other subdomain:

1. Get a new Generic SSL Certificate issued to your new subdomain
2. Get a **Wildcard SSL** Certificate, which are issued to a domain rather than a subdomain. For example a Wildcard Certificate is issued to `*.example.com`

I would recommend [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for free and (mostly) automated certificates.